# References of pub in Magento 2 VCL

Tags: magento2, varnish

Are we supposed to remove reference of pub from line 67,102,206 of VCL like we remove from line 13 if the Magento root directory is pub?

https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/882379061809b806fc5580729a6c9c78d782f84d#diff-2f64f6171deecba61bea147539cf72ec

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/varnish/config-varnish-advanced.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct, you have the following hidden in the varnish config guide on the Devdocs https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/varnish/config-varnish-advanced.html#health

> The health_check.php script is located in the pub directory. If your
>   Magento root directory is pub, then be sure to change the path in the
>   url parameter from `/pub/health_check.php` to `health_check.php`.

On a side note there is a active pull request currently in testing for this issue aswell

https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/25360

## Edit

A bit of further clarification, lines 102 + 206 are setup to work both from pub and from the app root. The `^(pub/)?` part of the url match means 0 or more instances of `pub/` at the start.

And if you want to run the health checks you need to update line 67 also to remove pub from that url match otherwise it wil cache the health check responses.

Comment: But are we supposed to remove other references as well? line 67,102,206 of VCL also refer to pub directory

Comment: Lines 102,206 are regex that is setup to work with and without pub. And line 62, yeah that needs to be updated aswell if you want to use the health checks. https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/25360/files#diff-2f64f6171deecba61bea147539cf72ecR67

Answer (score 1):

> Line 67

```
    if (req.url ~ "/pub/health_check.php") {
        return (pass);
    }
```

tells varnish not to cache this file `health_check.php` because it used to check your website status, varnish will request it every 5 seconds, if it gives 200 then your website is ok, if not - depending on your varnish configuration - you will get varnish `503 backend fetch error`.

same as in lines 102, 206. If you are not going to use cdn and want varnish to cache your media and static files comment line 104 and uncomment 207,208,209. if you are on cdn, leave it as is.

Comment: You didn't get my question. Magento documentation says remove 'pub' from line 13 if the Magento root directory is pub? So my question is why is they have not informed customers to remove other pub references as well.

Comment: if your Magento root is pub, then you should remove it from line 102 just not to cache the request, in line 13 you must remove to avoid 404 not found.
in line 102 `pub` is optional in this regex so it's no problem to leave it.